# SQL : i got an Ambiguous error

Tags: mysql, sql, ambiguous

```
select [CLIENT_SUIT_ID]
  ,[CLIENT_CODE]
  ,[CARD_ID]
  ,[EXPIRE_DATE]
  ,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by CARD_ID order by CARD_ID ASC)
from [KSS_TMP].[dbo].[CLIENT_SUIT] as Tab1 JOIN 
    (SELECT CARD_ID FROM [KSS_TMP].[dbo].[CLIENT_SUIT] 
     where CLIENT_CODE NOT LIKE '080%' AND CARD_ID != '-' 
     GROUP BY CARD_ID 
     HAVING COUNT(CARD_ID) > 1 ) as Tab2 ON Tab1.CARD_ID = Tab2.CARD_ID
```

when i tried to execute this code i got an "Ambiguous column name 'CARD_ID'. What did i do wrong here?

Comment: I tried tab1 and tab2, neither of them work

Comment: You have 6 uses of CARD_ID that could potentially cause a problem. The error means that the SQL parser is confused by one of those 6. The solution is to give every single table reference an alias, and then use that alias when referencing a column from that table. That keeps the parser clear on which one of the columns you intend it to use, which makes both you and the parser happy.

Comment: Thx Ken, i will have a look on that :)

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the table name on each select of `CARD_ID`, something like `SELECT Tab1.CARD_ID FROM ...`